# Why am I unable to extract values from multi dimentional arry

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I am using curl to fetch some external data.

```
$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_export($response) 
//I get the output as below:

'{ "value" : { "id" : 1090xxxx, "version" : 0, "url" : 
"tripletex.no/v2/token/session/1090xxxx", "consumerToken" : { "id" : 38xx, "url" : 
 "tripletex.no/v2/token/consumer/38xx" }, "employeeToken" : { "id" : 139xxx, "url" : 
 "tripletex.no/v2/token/employee/139xxx" }, "expirationDate" : "2022-01-01", "token" : 
 "a0a48845-2d7b-4375-aeb8-e1dcxxxxxx", "encryptionKey" : null } }'

//I then put the response into an array like this:
 $data=json_decode($response ,true);

print_r($data) //creates this output:
Array ( [value] => Array ( [id] => 10909xxxx [version] => 0 [url] => 
tripletex.no/v2/token/session/10909xxxx [consumerToken] => Array ( [id] => 38xx [url] => 
tripletex.no/v2/token/consumer/38xx ) [employeeToken] => Array ( [id] => 139xxx [url] => 
tripletex.no/v2/token/employee/139xxx ) [expirationDate] => 2022-01-01 [token] => a0a48845- 
2d7b-4375-aeb8-xxxxxxxx [encryptionKey] => ) )

echo ($data['value']['employeeToken']['token']);
```

What I’m trying ot achieve is to extract the value of the  [token].
I have tested various ways to make this work, but with no luck.
If anyone could point me in the right direction with a piece of code that would extract the data either out of the json response or our of the array?

Comment: `$data['value']['token']` is where it's located

Comment: If you're having trouble grokking the structure of some JSON, a JSON formatter might help, eg https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ (or just search, there are many).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are accessing the array incorrectly --  You are going into `[employeeToken]` which only has the two children of `[id]` and `[url]`.   You need `$data['value']['token']` to access the field you are looking for.

**SUGGESTION:** You are trying to access an array (by setting `json_decode` -> true) .. Whereas you should be trying to access it as an `Object` ..   This works "as is" stand-alone .. Tested ..

```
<?php

$response = '{ "value" : { "id" : "1090xxxx", "version" : 0, "url" : 
"tripletex.no/v2/token/session/1090xxxx", "consumerToken" : { "id" : "38xx", "url" : 
 "tripletex.no/v2/token/consumer/38xx" }, "employeeToken" : { "id" : "139xxx", "url" : 
 "tripletex.no/v2/token/employee/139xxx" }, "expirationDate" : "2022-01-01", "token" : 
 "a0a48845-2d7b-4375-aeb8-e1dcxxxxxx", "encryptionKey" : null } }';

// YOUR WAY
$data = json_decode($response, true);
echo $data['value']['token'] . "\n\n";

// MY SUGGESTION
$data = json_decode($response);
echo $data->value->token . "\n\n";
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the correct direction. Your suggestion works just like we wanted it to.